# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} 1/x = -\infty$

Tags: limits

Prove $\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1/x = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} 1/x = −\infty$. I am little confused by this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1/x$. Given any $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$, for all $x \in (0,1/M)$, we have $1/x > M$. Hence, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1/x = + \infty$$
Similarly, adapt the proof for the other case.